# Js open link in iframe on the parent from external domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am working with angular and wirecard payment provider.
When i need to add payment i am open in iframe the wirecard link to there site for user to accept the payment.
After he clicks accept i provide to wirecard link back to my site, but the problem is when i click accept the link is open in the iframe and not in the parent. How can i pass this?

```
<iframe ng-if="paymentIframeUrl" id="paymentIframe" ng-src="{{paymentIframeUrl}}" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>

PaymentsService.paymentMethodProccess(paymentMethod).then(function(res) {
 $scope.paymentIframeUrl = res.data.data.context.redirectUrl;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to **load** event on the iframe and check the url if this is your url then you can close the popup and do whatever you want.

for example:

```
document.getElementById("Iframe").addEventListener('load', function() {

try {
   var url = document.getElementById("Iframe").contentWindow.location.href;
   if( url.indexOf('yoururl') > -1 ) {
   //do what ever you want
   }
} catch {}

}
```